# Firebase Local Emulator Suite does not find the 'database.rules.json' file when started from CLI

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-tools

The `firebase.json` file:

```
{
  "emulators": 
    {
      "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
   "database": {
   "port": 9000,
   "rules": "database.rules.json",
   "target": "default"
   },
   "ui": {
     "enabled": true
     }
   }
 }
```

There is a `database.rules.json` file that sits next to the `firebase.json` file, containing the json rules which work correctly on the live database.

The files created automatically by the command:

> firebase init emulators

all are in the project root directory. I copied the rules from the live project, and created the `database.rules.json` file right next to the other files, like so:

```
ROOT
  |
  |.firebaserc
  |firebase.json
  |database.rules.json
```

However, the CLI command:

> $ firebase emulators:start

returns the following error:

> ⚠  database: Did not find a Realtime Database rules file specified in a firebase.json config file.

The emulator runs all right, but the rules are not taken into account.

Why is the 'database.rules.json' NOT found by the emulator? Is this a path issue?

Comment: Maybe you could share your project file and directory structure so we can see where the file actually is in relation to firebase.json and the rest of your project?

Comment: ok @DougStevenson, will edit...

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

firebase.json

```
{
  "functions": {
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "./firestore.rules"
  },
  "database": {
    "rules": "./database.rules.json"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "database": {
      "port": 9000
    },
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5000
    },
    "pubsub": {
      "port": 8085
    },
    "storage": {
      "port": 9199
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it did not work as expected was because a local database should have been initiated, but was not.

To initiate a local database, the following command should be used:

> firebase init database

As I had an existing database (created by the Realtime Console) which I had linked with my local project when using the interactive command:

> firebase init emulators

I thought I could then start the simulator and test away. Not so.

Failing to initiate a database with a CLI command seems to trigger the CLI response:

> ⚠ database: Did not find a Realtime Database rules file specified in a firebase.json config file

When what is really meant is:

> Duh, there is no local database. You must create a local database first, even if you link this project to an existing remote